# TM4C1294XL blink LED's in binary pattern

Tags: c, microcontroller, led

i am trying to produce the series of binary patterns corresponding to rising
unsigned integers using four LEDs in ports N anf F of the microcontroller. the LED pattern should display as follows:

0x00: (LLLL) 
0x01: (LLLH) 
0x02: (LLHL)
…
0x0F: (HHHH)
0x10: (LLLL)
0x11: (LLLH)
...

i cant seem to get the LED's to blink in this order in my while loop using a counter, how can i make this work? the microcontroller is a TM4C1294XL texas instruments and the program is in c code.

```
int main(void)
{
     /**
     * GPIO initialization
     */
    SYSCTL_RCGCGPIO_R |= 0x00001020 ; // enable port N & F
    while((SYSCTL_RCGCGPIO_R & 0x00001020) == 0); // wait until the port is available
    GPIO_PORTN_DEN_R = 0x03; // PN(0,1) enable
    GPIO_PORTN_DIR_R = 0x03; // PN(0,1) output
    GPIO_PORTF_AHB_DEN_R = 0x11; // PF(0,4) enable
    GPIO_PORTF_AHB_DIR_R = 0x11; // PF(0,4) output

     /**
     * TIMER initialization: compare mode
     */
    SYSCTL_RCGCTIMER_R |= (1<<1);
    while (!(SYSCTL_PRTIMER_R & (1<<1)) == 0);
    TIMER1_CTL_R &= ~(1<<0); // stop timer
    TIMER1_CFG_R = 0x4; // 16-bit
    TIMER1_TAMR_R |= 0x12; // periodic, upwards counting
    TIMER1_TAPR_R = 245-1; // prescalar value: timeout=1s, f(cpu)=16MHz
    TIMER1_TAILR_R = 65307-1; // interval load value: timeout=1s, f(cpu)=16MHz
    TIMER1_CTL_R |= (1<<0); // start timer

    unsigned int counter = 0;

     while(1)
     {
         counter++;

         while (GPIO_PORTN_DATA_R & counter == 0);
         GPIO_PORTN_DATA_R = counter;

         while (GPIO_PORTF_AHB_DATA_R & counter == 0);
         GPIO_PORTF_AHB_DATA_R = counter;

         while((TIMER1_RIS_R & (1<<0))==0);
         TIMER1_ICR_R |= (1<<0);
         GPIO_PORTN_DATA_R = 0x00;
         GPIO_PORTF_AHB_DATA_R = 0x00;
     }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you try to achieve by `while (GPIO_PORT... & counter == 0);`?

Comment: i'm not too sure...i just tried this but i dont quite understand it. do you have any other suggestions of what might work?

Comment: I suggest that you get enough understanding of each of the instructions you write into your own programs first. We cannot really help you with this, because it means learning on your side, like: reading, experimenting, failing, and all of these steps in loops. So, back to your C book and data sheet, little Padawan!

Comment: yes i know this, i am trying to learn but some help would really be appreciated. im finding it difficult to tackle this problem and would love an example of how this program could work so that i can learn from it.

Comment: Simplify: Try to blink a single LED. -- There should be some tutorial for your µC and your development environment, and there are tons of tutorials for embedded C. Use your favorite web search engine, (most important) your brain, and you will make it. -- To get familiar with a programming language, try to write some simple console-based PC programs. It is so much easier on this target to debug!

Comment: thankyou for this advice. yes i am able to get LED's blinking but it is this specific problem i would really like help with. i understand you dont want to provide any possible solutions so if anyone else can, i would appreciate the help

Comment: Well, if you have no reason for the instruction I asked about: What happens if you comment it out? -- Even if you don't know *exactly* why you wrote it: What do you think, does it?

Comment: its not an instruction its code.  But anyway, what is the problem here, are you able to blink leds?  with a busy loop in between state changes that burns time?  if not then dont mess with anything else but the leds, no timers.  if you can blink leds and that is not your problem then is it the use of the timer?  what debug resources do you have to understand the timer?  throwaway code like start it then take many samples of the registers stop the code and examine the array of samples or better print stuff out the uart and see things change.

Comment: you are I assume polling or at least started polling the timer and are not using interrupts? that would be an additional step, is that your issue?  or is it that you can work the gpio and timer but cant make the patter?   What is the question?

Comment: the question is i need to make the led blink in that specific patter 1sec apart using a timer and this has to be done with some kind of counter...the problem is i dont understand how this should be done which is why the code in the while loop doesnt make sense. i know how to code led's to blink specifically but what im trying to figure out is how to make some kind of loop with a counter so that the binary code of the counter defines which led to blink, so yes i can work the gpio and the timer but i cant make the pattern